# linear interpolation between values stored in separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, interpolation

I have numbers stored in 2 data frames (real ones are much bigger) which look like

df1

```
                  A        B          C      T        Z
13/03/2017      1.321674  3.1790  3.774602  30.898  13.22
06/02/2017      1.306358  3.1387  3.712554  30.847  13.36
09/01/2017      1.361103  3.2280  3.738500  32.062  13.75
05/12/2016      1.339258  3.4560  3.548593  31.978  13.81
07/11/2016      1.295137  3.2323  3.188161  31.463  13.43
```

df2

```
                   A        B       C        T        Z
13/03/2017      1.320829  3.1530  3.7418  30.933  13.1450
06/02/2017      1.305483  3.1160  3.6839  30.870  13.2985
09/01/2017      1.359989  3.1969  3.7129  32.098  13.6700
05/12/2016      1.338151  3.4215  3.5231  32.035  13.7243
07/11/2016      1.293996  3.2020  3.1681  31.480  13.3587
```

and a list where I have stored all daily dates from 13/03/2017 to 7/11/2016. 
I would like to create a dataframe with the following features:

- the list of daily dates is the indexrow
- I would like to create columns (in this case from A to Z)  and for each row/ day  compute the linear interpolation value between the value in df1 and the corresponding value in df2 shifted by -1. For example, in the row '12/03/2017' for column A I want to compute [(34/35)*1.321674]+[(1/35)*1.305483] = 1.3212114. Where 35 is the number of days between 13/03/2017 and 06/02/2017, 1.321674 is the value in df1 corresponding to column A for the day 13/03/2017 and 1.305483 is the value in df2 corresponding to column A for the day 06/02/2017. For 11/03/2017 for column A I want to compute [(33/35)*1.321674]+[(2/35)*1.305483] = 1.3207488. Thus keeping fixed the values 1.321674 and 1.305483 for the time interval until 6/2/2017 where it should show 1.305483.
- Finally, the linear interpolation should shift interpolating values when the corresponding row shows a date which is the next time interval. For example, once I reach 05/02/2017, the linear interpolation should be between 1.306358 (df1, column A) and 1.359989 (df2, column B), that is shift one position down.

For clarity, date format is 'dd/mm/yyyy'

I would greatly appreciate any piece of advice or suggestion, I am aware it's a lot of work so any hint is valued! 
Please let me know if I you need more clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: how you are interpolating is not clear. I think one workflow can be, you can combine 2 dataframes, make sure your dataframe index is datetime, resample dataframe to daily frequency, then interpolate among the dataframe

Comment: I am doing linear interpolation between 2 numbers over some period of time. Basically I want to know what would be the weighted average of the 2 numbers at some day with time as weights. For instance if I want to know the number exactly in the middle of the time period it would be a combination of (1/2*x)+(0.5*y) where x and y are the numbers for df1 and df2 respectively.